# How to drag a pointer inside a pointer of class objects and assign them recursively then return a pointer? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

Assume the following:

- I have a class called `Person`:

```js
class Person {
  public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    int compare(const Person & compared); //compare the names using strcmp()
    void display();
    
  protected:
    char * name;
    int age;
};
```

- I use a `Linked_List` data structure to store a list of `Person` objects:

```js
class Linked_List {
  public:
    Linked_List();
    ~Linked_List();
    Person * retreive(Person, Node *, int &);
    void insert(Person);
    int remove_all();
    int display_all();
    
  protected:
    Node * head;
};
```

- `retrieve()` function should return a list of `Person` objects that has the same name with the one being passed to the function (RECURSIVELY).

```js
Person * Linked_List::retreive(Person target, Node * current, int & matches) {
    if (current == NULL) {
        Person * persons = new Person[matches];
        return persons;
    }
    if (target.compare(current->getData()) == 0) {
        return retreive(target, current->getNext(), ++matches); //recursive call
    }
    return retreive(target, current->getNext(), matches); //recursive call
}
```

This function takes in three arguments

1- The person I am looking for. (To compare the name with the others on the list)

2- The head pointer. (To traverse through the list recursively)

3- The number of `Person` objects that was found on the list with the same name of the target `Person`. (To allocate the dynamic array of persons with the same name that was found on the list)

This function basically traverses through the `Linked_List` recursively and every time a match `Person` is found, `matches` increase by one and then do a recursive call to keep traversing. Until the end of the list is reached, then the array of `Person` objects gets allocated dynamically. Then I reach my problem. I couldn't think of a way to make this function work successfully, UNLESS I find a way that allows me to store (assign) each object of `Person` found as a match inside the array of `persons` being returned at the end of traversal (the recursive call).

**So, what I am really trying to do is something like this (This is wrong, but just for clarity purposes):**

Since the function returns an array of `Person`, then I will write inside the second condition

`return (retreive(target, current->getNext(), matches))[matches++] = current->getPerson();`

I want to store every `Person` that have the same name in an array of `Person` objects, but I also have to wait until I reach the end of the recursive call so I can initialize the the array with the correct size of the number of matched persons, YET I also need to return an array (*) of `Person` objects not only one object.

Comment: Have you considered using a dynamic iterative container to store the persons? (Such as `std::vector` or a similar implementation) Then you would not need to reiterate through the list twice first counting them, and then returning an array of correct Persons.

Comment: @ChrisBritt I am actually not traversing twice, this is why this is a little challenging problem. Thank you though, I'll consider what you've suggested. But, for the sake of curiosity, I'll wait to see if there is a solution for my problem, OR maybe not.

Comment: Just curious, `compare` returns 0 if a match, and !0 for not a match? (Are you passing additional info from it? If not, you might want to use a bool for readability purposes.)

Comment: 0 if equal, -1 if less, 1 if larger. Identical to `strcmp()` function. @ChrisBritt

Comment: I wrote up a version that uses a vector as a temporary cache. If your interested I could post it. As it is passing the vector by reference, its overhead is not much higher, and provides a clean way to assign the values at the end of the iteration. (As Sam has already given a nice answer, I figured I would ask first.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple once you realize a simple fact. Let's say that on the given iteration, nmatches is 0, and you found a record that `compare()` claims matches the target.

This means that this is the first matching record. This means that, in the returned array, this match will go into `persons[0]`.

If nmatches is 1, that means that this match will go into `persons[1]`, and so on.

This means that this becomes, simply:

```
Person * Linked_List::retreive(Person target, Node * current, int & matches) {
    if (current == NULL) {
        Person * persons = new Person[matches];
        return persons;
    }
    if (target.compare(current->getData()) == 0) {
        int n=matches;

        auto p=retreive(target, current->getNext(), ++matches);
        p[n]=current->getData();
        return p;
    }
    return retreive(target, current->getNext(), matches); //recursive call
}
```

That's it. Your homework assignment, however, is to get rid of the ugly `new`, and rewrite the whole thing using `std::vector`. With modern C++, one rarely needs to manually `new` and `delete` anything. There's a container for every need and desire, and, as an extra bonus, there won't be any memory leaks when containers are used properly. What a bargain!

Answer (score 0):

This sample utilizes a `std::vector<Person*>` for the purpose of acting as both a temporary cache, and will also return this vector to the user in addition to the array of pointers. I am operating under the assumption that the Node::getData() returns a pointer to the data element. (Fairly certain that is fairly standard practice.) You also can change the return type to void, and thus completely remove the need for the array as you are also getting the return of the std::vector containing the data. (Using arrays with `new` / `delete` is rather antiquated due to the versatility of the STL containers. )

*Just as a note, the variable `int & matches` is now contained within `std::vector::size()`.*

```
Person * Linked_List::retreive(Person target, Node * current, std::vector<Person*>& _persons) {
    if (current == NULL) {
        Person * persons = new Person[_persons.size()];
        for(int i(0); i < _persons.size(); ++i)
        {
            persons[i] = &_persons[i];
        }
        return persons;
    }
    if (target.compare(current->getData()) == 0) {
        _persons.push_back(current->getData());
        return retreive(target, current->getNext(), _persons); //recursive call
    }
    return retreive(target, current->getNext(), _persons); //recursive call
}
```